# regex for parsing complex line of numbers

Tags: python, regex, numbers

Im trying to parse a line of numbers that looks like this

> 38.97 -99.63$    0.6512.00    1   0 185.00   0 -126.00     1.750    4.87

I would like to extract all numbers to a precision of 2 digits after the dot. I also would like to extract the number with the missing space "0.6512.00"

I come up with this

> (-?(?:\d+(?:.\d{0,2})?))

but the problem is, that it splits 1.750 to 1.75 and 0

does anyone have an idea how to solve this?
thanks

Comment: You could put `\d*` outside the parentheses to include the additional digits in the match but not the capture. I'd suggest experimenting with e.g. https://regex101.com/#python

Comment: And how `0.6512.00` should be split? `0.651` (removing the 1) and `2.00` or  `0.65` and `12.00`?

Comment: can't you just split the text with `.split()` and process each word separably?

Comment: the regex should assume that normally the values have 2 digits after the dot. I know its not perfect. So it should split 0.65 12.00

Comment: You should be escaping the dot in your expression, because that symbol will match any character. Which could mean you will accidentally match `12.34` and `56789` from the string `12.3456789`. You can escape it a couple of ways such as `\.` or `[.]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(-?\b(?:\d+\.\d{0,2}(?!0*[1-9])|(?<!\d\.)\d+(?!\.\d)))0*\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yH3mJ6/2)

The main point is using 2 alternatives, one for float values - `\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})(?!0*[1-9])` - with 2 digits in the decimal part, and the other - `(?<!\d\.)\d+(?!\.\d)` - for matching integer values. The trailing `0*` will match for floats, but will not be captured. *Use Group 1 value*.

Comment: This does neither extract the number with the missing space nor manages the `1.750` which does not even match

Comment: @Francesco: Have you had a look at the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJ7hJ4/1)? `1.750` should not match as it has 3 digits in the decimal part, and it does  match `0.6512.00`

Comment: I suspect this is not what he asked but I leave it to @manuel

Comment: I agree it sounds unclear. Do you understand it as `1.75` should match as the trailing `0` is optional? And what should match in `0.6512.00` then?

Comment: I think that 1.750 should match but he only wants to extract 1.75. And I think that he wants somehow to split `0.6512.00` into two numbers. For this last one I asked more info in a comment since there isn't only one way to split this.

Comment: 1.750 should match as 1.75, but apart from that, this look good.

Comment: @manuel: Check https://regex101.com/r/dV1hW5/2. However, it is not clear what to do in case of `22.12.22`.

Comment: @manuel: It would help if you provide all test cases with expected output.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I've got it sorted with your idea and some programming logic around.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
\d+\b\.\b(?:(?!\.| )[0-9]){2}
```

the output will be 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two pennies worth:

```
[-+]?\d+(?:(?:\.\d+)(?![.\d])|(?:\.\d{1,2}))?
```

It allows an optional sign followed by a range of digits, then optionally followed by -

a dot (`.`) and a range of digits, **not** ended by a dot, **or**...

a dot and 1 or 2 decimals.

It fills all the criteria with the addition (exception?) of rounding the 3+ decimal numbers, i.e. it leaves that to the number parser since `1.750` should be rounded to `1.75`, and `1.758` should round to `1.76`, and there's no way regex will do that correctly ;).

[Se it work here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kP4pI4/2).

Regards

**Edit** slight simplification of regex and description